# Why should I subclass BaseEstimator in a Scikit-Learn Pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

In the scikit-learn documentation they give [examples](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py) of custom Transformers which subclass both the **BaseEstimator** and **TransformerMixin** classes. I'm wondering, why is the **BaseEstimator** subclass used in these examples?

To try and answer this question, I took it out of the **ItemSelector** class, but Python did not complain.

Comment: It depends on how you intend to use the pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`BaseEstimator`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html#sklearn.base.BaseEstimator) provides an implementation of the `get_params` and `set_params` methods. Why is this needed? It can be used to make a model applicable to [`GirdSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.get_params). This ensures it behaves well when placed in a pipeline. This is just one of the applications for the `BaseEstimator`

In the example you provided, no grid search is performed, which is why it was not needed. It is included in most places (I believe) for best practice, essentialy future proofing your code for the insertion of a grid search into the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

**BaseEstimator** provides among other things a default implementation for the **get_params** and **set_params** methods, see [[the source code]](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L175). This is useful to make the model grid search-able with **GridSearchCV** for automated parameters tuning and behave well with others when combined in a Pipeline.